# Can't login, kde loads, then back to kdm

Tags: 10.10, login-screen, kubuntu, login

Hello to all (K)Ubuntu users,
I installed Kubuntu 10.10 after it's release. 
(I used to use ubuntu, I want to try kubuntu now)

Now I can't login in Kubuntu:
When(/if) I login with my username and password, KDE loads(I mean the splashscreen),
but if it's ready nearly, the screen becomes dark and I'm back in the login-manager.

I tried many things:
With a new user or
with installing `gdm` or
install it new (two times!)

Thank you for helping

PS: Ubuntu works normal

**EDIT:**
 The text-console-mode(or however it's named in english) isn't working at all,seems like a graphics bug or something similiar.
And there aren't very many (hidden) ".folders", just `.kde` `.config` `.dbus` `.fontconfig` and some ".files".

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the kde configurations for the user by moving the `.kde` directory in the users home directory to a different name and see if you can then log in.

Often these problems are incompatibilities or something that is reminiscent from a crash that causes such problems.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I've tried it but it doesn't work.  It's ordinary that in the home folder not many ".folders" are, after a fresh install and before a (successful) login?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have this sorted out by now as October 14th was awhile ago. I would install another desktop environment or exit to a command prompt from the login screen using Session manager. Login but from the command line. Then I would do an update and install any upgrades.

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
startx

Sometimes in an upgrade not everything gets installed properly and you get a partial upgrade. Strange things like this can happen. A full upgrade usually sorts it out.

Comment: Unfortunely it doesn't work.